# what's the best way to integrate $\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[4] {x^3 +1}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have to integrate
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[4]{x^3+1}} \,dx$$

To solve this, I've tried various substitutions including
a) let $x^{3/2}$=$e^{2u},$ which leads  to the following integral
$$\frac{4}{3} \int \frac{e^{2x}}{\sqrt [4] {e^{4x}+1}}du$$ which, according to integral calculator.net, has no closed form.
I also tried the following $u$-sub let $u=x^{3/2}.$ However that didn't help much either, so what is the sub, if any that I must use here.

Edit:- My book does give the answer, but not the method, @greg Martin suggested I add that as it may help, so here it is

$\frac{4}{3} (\sqrt[4] {x^3} -\ln(\sqrt[4]{x^3} +1)) +C $

This problem is from N.Piskunov's  Differential and integral calculus , Volume 1

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+x%5E%281%2F2%29%2F%28x%5E3%2B1%29%5E%281%2F4%29+dx) does not know a closed form for this integral that doesn't involve hypergeometric functions.

Comment: yeah, however, my book has given an answer in terms of standard functions, however, I don't know how t obtain it

Comment: I recommend adding that fact, with the specific solution, to the question. That will probably help people find an answer for you.

Comment: ok, will do , thanks

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever the book's answer is wrong, or the question is wrong. The derivative of the answer is $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[4]{x^3}+1}$

Comment: oh, OK. Thanks, in that case it must have been a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only solution is given in terms of Gauss hypergeometric function.
$$\frac 1{\sqrt[4]{t+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-\frac{1}{4}}{n} t^n$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[4]{x^3+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-\frac{1}{4}}{n} x^{3 n+\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[4]{x^3+1}} \,dx=\frac 2 3  x^{3/2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{-\frac{1}{4}}{n} }{2 n+1} x^{3 n}=\frac{2}{3} x^{3/2} \,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-x^3\right)$$

Comment: FYI, it is possible to reduce this hypergeometric function to an elliptic integral with the right substitution.

Comment: @DavidH. I was thinking about ... but did not find it. Could you tell me what is the right substitution ? Thanks & cheers.

Comment: The substitution $\sqrt{x^{3}+1}=t$ is enough to transform it into something recognizable as an elliptic integral. From there use your favorite algorithm to put it in standard form. ;)

Comment: @DavidH. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2):

Your integral is of a type of integrals known as the [differential binomial](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Differential_binomial):

$$ \int x^m(a+bx^n)^p\,dx\qquad a,b\in\mathbb{R}, \,m, n, p\in\mathbb{Q}$$
The change of variables $x=t^{1/n}$ yields
$$ \int x^m(a+bx^n)^p\,dx = \frac1n\int (a+bt)^p t^{\tfrac{m+1}{n}-1}\,dt $$

[P. L. Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pafnuty_Chebyshev) studied these integrals and  proved that there are only three cases in which they are *solvable*, in the sense that a primitive (antiderivative) can be found in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)):

1. $p\in\mathbb{Z}$: If $q=\frac{m+1}{n}-1=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $g.c.d(\alpha,\beta)=1$, then the substitution $z=t^{1/\beta}$ reduced the integral to one of a rational fraction.
2. $q\in\mathbb{Z}$: the substitution $z=(a+bt)^{1/\beta}$ reduced to integral to one of a rational fraction.
3. $p+q\in\mathbb{Z}$. The change of variable $z=\Big(\frac{a+bt}{t}\Big)^{1/\beta}$ reduces the integral to one of a rational fraction

In your case, the substitution $x=t^{1/3}$ ($\frac13 t^{-2/3} dt=dx$) yields to
$$\int x^{1/2}(x^3+1)^{-1/4} \,dx=\frac13\int(1+t)^{-1/4}t^{-1/2}\,dt
$$
None of the conditions (1)-(3) hold; hence there is no *elementary* primitive.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!